# pip issues in Windows

Tags: python, pip

I just installed a brand new copy of Python in Win7 using `python-3.4.3.amd64.msi`.

During the install log, I saw mention of `pip` getting installed. But when I try to use it:

```
>>> pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pip' is not defined
>>>
```

Or even trying `pip` from the Windows CLI returns invalid command.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need pip installation directory to add it to your users PATH variable which can be found in `Control panel->System->Environmental variables".

So if your pip binary is in c:\python3.4\bin then you would append the path variable with `c:\python3.4\bin`. Remember to separate each added directory with a `;`!

And as mentioned, pip is CLI, calling it from interpreter gets you nowhere ;)

Comment: Right okay, looks like pip is in a folder called `Scripts`

Comment: @Zeno possibly, I didn't do that on windows in a while. Just add the folder containing pip.exe to your `PATH`, start a new console window and you are good to go.

Comment: just make sure the length of your path doesn't go over 2048 characters, this can cause some very very strange errors